# Conditions on a topological space implying that it has a minimal basis

Tags: general-topology

This is a question I've had in the back of my mind for a while, motivated by curiosity.

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space, and consider $\mathfrak{F}=\{B\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X):B \text{ is a basis for }\tau\}$ partially ordered by inclusion. Are there reasonable conditions on $\tau$ that ensure the existence of minimal elements in $(\mathfrak{F},\subseteq)$?  (I know that if $\tau$ is finite, then there is a minimal basis for $\tau$, but this is hardly interesting.)

In particular, does $\Bbb R$ with the standard topology have a minimal basis?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am unaware of any "nice" characterisation of spaces with minimal bases, but using the following one is able to show that a wide class of spaces do not have this property. It's not so much a characterisation of such spaces as a characterisation of the (necessarily unique) minimal base of a topological space which has one.

Given a topological space $X$, we call $x \in X$ a *base point* of $X$ if it  has a smallest open neighbourhood in $X$. In this case we denote this smallest open neighbourhood by $U(x)$.

**Theorem.** A topological space $X$ has a minimal base iff $\mathcal{M}(X) = \{ U(x) : x\text{ is a base point of }X \}$ is a (minimal) base for $X$.

Before we really begin, note the following observations.

**Fact 1.** If $\mathcal{B}$ is a minimal base for $X$, then for each $\mathcal{B}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, if $\bigcup \mathcal{B}_0 \in \mathcal{B}$, then $\bigcup \mathcal{B}_0 \in \mathcal{B}_0$.

- *proof.* Suppose that $\mathcal{B}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ is such that $U = \bigcup \mathcal{B}_0 \in \mathcal{B}$ and $U \notin \mathcal{B}_0$. Then as every set in the base $\mathcal{B}$ is the union of a subfamily of $\mathcal{B} \setminus \{ U \}$, it follows that $\mathcal{B}_0 \setminus \{ U \}$ is a base for $X$, contradicting the minimality of $\mathcal{B}$!

**Fact 2.** If $x$ is a base point for a topological space $X$, then $U(x) \in \mathcal{D}$ for every base $\mathcal{D}$ of $X$.

- *proof.* There must be a $V \in \mathcal{D}$ with $x \in V \subseteq U(x)$, but by definition of $U(x)$ it must be that $V = U(x)$.

We now turn to the proof of the theorem.

- **(⇒)** Suppose that $X$ has a minimal base $\mathcal{B}$. Given $U \in \mathcal{B}$, I claim that $U = U(x)$ for some (base point) $x \in X$. Otherwise for each $x \in U$ there is a $V_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $V_x \subsetneq U$. But then $\bigcup_{x \in U} V_x = U$, contradicting Fact 1!

  Therefore $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{M}(X)$, and since by Fact 2 we have $\mathcal{M}(X) \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, it follows that $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{M}(X)$, as desired (*i.e.*, $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a minimal base for $X$).
- **(⇐)** Suppose that $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a base for $X$. Using Fact 2 we have that $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is a subset of every base for $X$, and so $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is in fact a *minimal* base for $X$.

---

With regards to $\mathbb{R}$ under the usual topology, it is easy to show that it has no minimal base, since it has *no* base points. In fact, something much stronger can be said.

**Proposition.** If $X$ is a T<sub>1</sub>-space with a minimal base, then $X$ is discrete.

- *proof.* Suppose that $X$ is a T<sub>1</sub>-space. If $x \in X$ is non-isolated, then it can be shown that $x$ has no smallest open neighbourhood.  (Every open neighbourhood of $x$ is infinite, by and removing finitely many points distinct from $x$ we get a smaller open neighbourhood.)  If $x \in X$ is isolated, then $\{ x \}$ is the minimal open neighbourhood of $X$; *i.e.*, $x$ is a base point of $X$, and $U(x) = \{ x \}$.

  Then $\mathcal{M}(X) = \{ \{ x \} : x\text{ is isolated in }X \}$, and is a base for $X$ exactly when *every* point of $X$ is isolated; *i.e.*, if $X$ is discrete.

---

One interesting class of spaces which have minimal bases is the class of [Alexandrov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology). A topological space $X$ is *Alexandrov* if it satisfies any/all of the following equivalent conditions (among many more):

1. The family of open subsets of $X$ is closed under arbitrary (nonempty) intersections.
2. The family of closed subsets of $X$ is closed under arbitrary unions.
3. Every $x \in X$ has a smallest open neighbourhood, *i.e.*, every $x \in X$ is a base point of $X$.

Using the last property above and the Theorem it is easy to show that every Alexandrov space has a minimal base. There are examples of spaces with a minimal base which are not Alexandrov.

**Example.** The family $\mathcal{B} = \{ [x,+\infty) : x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is a minimal base for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$. This topological space is not Alexandrov, as no irrational number is a base point.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer. We first give an answer for $\mathbb R$ and then a quick generalisation:

Lots of spaces do not satisfy this property. Take $X=\mathbb R$ and suppose such a minimal basis $\mathcal B$ exists. Pick $\varnothing\ne B\in\mathcal B$ and find $x<y$ inside it. Let $U=B\cap (-\infty, x+\frac23(y-x)),$ $V= B\cap (x+\frac13(x-y),\infty)$ be open. Then $B\ne U,V\ne\varnothing$ and $U\cup V=B$ and so by expressing $U,V$ as unions from the basis, we can express $b$ as the union of those unions. Hence $\mathcal B-B\subset\mathcal B$ is a basis but is strictly smaller.

For a general space $X$ the following properties are sufficient for $X$ to not admit a minimal basis:

1. $X$ is a $T_{2{^1\!/_2}}$ space (points are separable by closed sets)
2. $X$ is nonempty
3. $X$ does not have the discrete topology.

The proof is the basically the same except you take just $x\ne y$ and use $U=B\cap(X-U'), V=B\cap(X-V')$ where $U',V'$ are a separation of $x,y$ by closed sets.

Properties 2 and 3 are equivalent to “any basis must have an element of cardinality at least 2”

If $X$ has the discrete topology then the set of singletons is a minimal basis.

I do not know about such minimal bases for other spaces.

Comment: Actually your answer made me realize that I meant minimal basis in the sense that no proper subcollection is a basis, but turns out that this is an interesting question too as your answer shows, I guess I'll ask another question later!

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I'm not sure what you mean by subcollection. Surely it makes very little difference whether you call your basis a set or a collection.

Comment: Hm, wait, you're right, it makes no difference. I'm confused now, I know that the Borel $\sigma$ algebra of $\Bbb R$ admits a minimal generating set (a collection such that no proper subcollection is a generating set) as does every countably generated $\sigma$ algebra, by a 1981 result of Bhaskara-Rao, I expected this to translate to a minimal basis but apparently it does not

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti the key difference is of course that a topological basis only allows unions (you can go bigger than basis elements but not smaller) so the proof works by breaking up big sets into smaller ones whereas in a $\sigma-$algebra you are allowed complements and countable intersections too. Countable intersections restricts things quite a bit but intersections in general can be used to break up big sets into smaller ones.