# Base of a Topological space

Tags: general-topology

We normally define the concept of topological space $(X,\tau)$ before the notion of base for $\tau$. My question is : Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space Does always exists a base? for $\tau$ different from trivial bases as $\tau$ itself or
$\tau$ $\setminus${$X$} if $\tau$ is $T_1$. Avoiding also trivial cases in which $\tau$ is the indiscrete topology or discrete topology. Given $\mathcal B$ the set of bases for $\tau$ does it have minimal  elements?

Comment: Does the discrete topology fall under your notion for "trivial"?

Comment: Thanks for the observation

Comment: Can you please edit to clarify your question?  "for τ different from..." is not clear. Which topologies do you exclude, and for the remaining ones, which basis? Also, only 1 question please, and present your attempts to solve it. (I think you can easily find a topological space for which the set of bases has no minimal element, so you can discard your last sentence.)

Comment: This answers your last sentence: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255981/conditions-on-a-topological-space-implying-that-it-has-a-minimal-basis?rq=1

Comment: Yes this answer, even very well. Thanks